# open submenu when hover on parent

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with multiple submenus in it. When on a smartphone the menu opens all submenus but it is becoming too long and so I want it to open only when clicked on its parent. I made it hidden using this

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

and then I did this:

```
#cssmenu ul  ul  li:hover > #cssmenu ul ul ul li{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

so that when I hover on it it appears back but this isn't working.
What can I do please?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
#cssmenu ul  ul  li:hover > ul {visibility:visible;}
```

But I would suggest you to use `display:none` and `display:block` though.

Comment: Thanks that worked :) As you said I used the display property to eliminate the space between parents

Comment: You are welcome :) Please check this as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu
{
 width: 500px;
 height: 43px;
 background:#14AABE;
}

.menu ul
{
 list-style: none;
 width: 744px;
 height: 43px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li
{
 float: left;
 width: 86px;
 height: 43px;
 line-height: 43px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 80px;
}
.menu ul li:hover
{
 background: #14AABE;
}

.menu ul li:hover #ul
{
 display: block;
}

.menu ul li a
{
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#ul
{
 list-style: none;
 color: #FFF;
 display: none;
 width: 215px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 10px 0;
 background: #454545;
 opacity: 0.9;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
}

#li
{
 float: none;
 width: auto;
 height: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
#li:hover
{
 background: none;
}
#li:hover #ulul
{
 display: block;
}
#li a
{
 font-size: 12px;
}
#li a:hover
{
 color: #14AABE;
}
#ulul
{
 list-style: none;
 color: #FFF;
 display: none;
 font-size: 12px;
 min-width: 230px;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 background: #454545;
 opacity: 0.9;
 margin: -25px 0 0 200px;
 padding: 5px 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#lili
{
 float: none;
 width: auto;
 height: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
#lili:hover
{
 background: none;
}
.active
{
 background: #14AABE;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
 <li  class="active"  ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li  ><a href="#">Products</a>
  <ul id="ul">
   <li id="li"><a href="#">BOOK CASES / SHOW CASES</a></li>
   <li id="li"><a href="#">CHAIRS</a>
    <ul id="ulul">
     <li id="lili"><a href="#">Office Chairs</a></li>
     <li id="lili"><a href="#">Home Chairs</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="li"><a href="#">CABINETS</a></li>
   <li id="li"><a href="#">FILING CABINETS</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```